Poem/Tokio server freezes with CLOSE-WAIT socket
In rust, I'm using the poem-openapi flavor of the poem framework with the tokio runtime to implement a web application. The problem is that during load testing with goose the server freezes after many sockets get stuck in the CLOSE-WAIT state. Usually 4,000 to 8,000 requests succeed before the web app freezes.
Any thoughts are appreciated. Here's how I initialize the server:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
....
        poem::Server::new(
            TcpListener::bind(addr).rustls(
                RustlsConfig::new().fallback(
                    RustlsCertificate::new()
                        .key(std::fs::read(key)?)
                        .cert(std::fs::read(cert)?),
                ),
            ),
        )
        .name(SERVER_NAME)
        .idle_timeout(Duration::from_secs(60))
        .run(app)
        .await
}

Here's how one of the endpoints is defined:
#[OpenApi]
impl NewSshKeysApi {
    #[oai(path = "/tms/pubkeys/creds", method = "post")]
    async fn get_new_ssh_keys(&self, http_req: &Request, req: Json<ReqNewSshKeys>) -> TmsResponse {
        match RespNewSshKeys::process(http_req, &req) {
            Ok(r) => r,
            Err(e) => {
                // Assume a server fault if a raw error came through.
                let msg = "ERROR: ".to_owned() + e.to_string().as_str();
                error!("{}", msg);
                make_http_500(msg)
            }
        }
    }
}

